# Featured on Meta widget missing :visited style

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sidebar, community-bulletin

Pretty self-explanatory. Basically all links on stack exchange use `#07C` as the default colour, and `#005999` for the `:visited`, `:active`, and `:hover` states (or whatever the colours happen to be for a given SE site's styling). However, the new styling for the "Featured on Meta" widget seems to be missing the style for `:visited`. Please put it back. My brain is programmed to ignore `#005999` and I thought there was new stuff for a minute when the new styling showed up.

FWIW, the `:hover` and `:active` state styles are still working. It seems like this selector on line 2052 of primary.css:

```
.s-anchors.s-anchors__default a:not(.s-link):hover,.s-anchors .s-anchors.s-anchors__default a:not(.s-link):hover,.s-anchors.s-anchors__default a:not(.s-link):active,.s-anchors .s-anchors.s-anchors__default a:not(.s-link):active {
    color: #005999
}
```

needs `a:not(.s-link):visited,.s-anchors` or something?

[image: featured on meta]

In case it happens to be relevant, I'm using Chrome 74.0.3729.108 64-bit on CentOS 7.6.1810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that our [design framework](https://stackoverflow.design/) wasn't applying `:visited` and `:hover` styles correctly. This is now fixed in production. Thanks for the report!